# How to see HTTP errors like Chrome in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, http

I'm getting only blank pages when an error like HTTP 500 occurs, in Firefox.

However, in Chrome, I get the following:

```
Esta página no funciona
La página inetserv.visa.com.ar no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Is there any way to get the same in Firefox? Because a blank page is some times confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox the HTTP Status Code extension allows you to have the HTTP Code of the page you're looking at.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in about:config that relates to a 500 response code.

But I usually look at the Developer Tools, Network tab, select the response from the server, and that shows me the full set of headers.